# how to use concatenate command inside the awk command

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am trying to print the multiple columns from the file with different sub commands with the  `awk` command.

Below is my command which throws error while using concatenate command with `awk`

```
awk -F\| '{if(length($1) == 12 && $21 == "SOUTHWEST") print $1 "," substr($2,5,9) "," c == $3$15; print  c }' sample.txt | head > test.csv
```

error thrown as "syntax error near c"

sample.txt will contains data like

```
0011D959A6BC|308-452591505|70605|1|1|TCD2000||LK012|0|||1|0||2581|850|La‌​ke Charles, LA|308|||SOUTHWEST|null|Lake Charles, LA|1|A9200019036CF2B|1|1|0
```

Expected output: `0011D959A6BC,452591505,706052581`

I used below syntax as example to concatenate in my script

```
echo '12345|123|6789'| awk -F\| '{c=$1$2; print c}'
```

Comment: Post the error along with an input sample (and expected output).

Comment: What is `c` here? What is `c == $3$15`, is it supposed to be assignment or comparison?...

Comment: sample.txt will contains data like 
**0011D959A6BC**|308-**452591505**|**70605**|1|1|TCD2000||LK012|0|||1|0||**2581**|850|Lake Charles, LA|308|||SOUTHWEST|null|Lake Charles, LA|1|A9200019036CF2B|1|1|0
Expected output: 0011D959A6BC,452591505,706052581

syntax error near c

I used below syntax to concatenate
echo '12345|123|6789'| awk -F\| '{c=$1$2; print c}'

Comment: that's unreadable in a comment.  by 'post the error...', @don_christi meant 'edit your question and add the additional information (and format it correctly)', not 'post a comment'.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you found, the `c` variable is useless, you can directly concatenate strings (here fields) and print the result.

Here is a way to achieve what your want to do:

```
awk -F\| '{
  if(length($1) == 12 && $21 == "SOUTHWEST")
    printf("%s , %s, %s\n",$1 ,substr($2,5,9),$3$15)
  }' sample.txt | head > text.csv
```